# How to save api response in a variable in mocha?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, supertest

I am calling an api and want to save a particular response value(id) in a variable so that I can use the same id in further test cases.

```
    it('1: Valid userId', function (done) {
    servicesGenerator.getPlayoApi(apiEndPoints.getValidFetchPlaypalsApi())
        .end(function (err, res) {
            baseValidator(err, res, 1, responseMsg.fetchPlaypalsSuceess);
            done();
        });
});
```

How can I extract the desired value from the response body and use it outside the it().

I want to do something like

```
var palId;
it('1: Valid userId', function (done) {
servicesGenerator.getPlayoApi(apiEndPoints.getValidFetchPlaypalsApi())
    .end(function (err, res) {
        palId=res.body.pal[0].palId
        baseValidator(err, res, 1, responseMsg.fetchPlaypalsSuceess);
        done();
    });
```

});

and then use this palId anywhere in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a variable and use it that way:

```
describe('test suite', function() {
  let component;

  beforeEach(function() {
   return asyncFunction();
  });

  it('test', () => {
    // use variable here
  });
});
```

Comment: I want to get the value of the variable from inside the it() and then use it outside the it() block.

Comment: Component variable is available for all of the it() , so change in one it() will be available in others and in the outer scope too